# Can't Add My Service Reference

Tags: wcf-data-services, service-reference

I have a WCF Data service that I was able to add to my project yesterday. Nothing that I can figure out has changed since then, but now when I delete that reference and try to re-add it, I get the following error:

> *This service cannot be consumed by the current project. Please check if the project target framework supports this service type.*

I am able to browse to the data service URL and the $metadata looks right. I can't seem to find much info on this error

Both the wcf service and the project is .net 4

Comment: What is the project target framework? 3.5 or 4.0 or 4.5?

Comment: I ran into the same issue today.  The project target version is 4.5.1